# Error using SpeedFan - how can I control fan speed?

Tags: fan

I'm new to the whole Linux concept. I start up SpeedFan and it comes up with a error saying "Privileged instruction". I'm very new to this, so if someone could tell me how to fix this step by step, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpeedFan is a Windows-only program. It will not work in Linux. There is an application in the default Ubuntu repositories that has similar functionality to SpeedFan called *Psensor*. Psensor is an application for monitoring hardware sensors, including temperatures and fan speeds.

Install Psensor. Also install lm-sensors to detect your computer's hardware sensors, and detect your computer's hardware sensors by running these commands:

```
sudo apt install psensor lm-sensors sensors-applet
sudo sensors-detect
```

Then you will get asked a lot of questions about what hardware you want the program to detect.  It is generally safe and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions, unless you know what you're doing.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later Psensor detects your computer's hardware sensors automatically without running `sudo sensors-detect`

Psensor displays itself on the desktop as a little thermometer icon in the notification area in the upper right corner of the desktop. You can right-click the thermometer icon at any time to display the hardware temperatures.