# Seeking recommendations for hardware monitoring and fan control GUI programs on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

I'm relatively new to the Ubuntu environment and I'm looking for some guidance regarding hardware monitoring tools and fan control options. After doing some research, I've found that it might be a bit challenging to find suitable programs for these tasks. I'm hoping you could provide some recommendations or suggestions based on your experience.
Specifically, I'm in search of a user-friendly GUI program that can provide me with hardware monitoring capabilities similar to what GPU-Z and CPU-Z offer on other platforms. (I have RTX 4090, I7-13700K). Additionally, I'm also interested in finding a program that allows for fan speed control. I believe this could be helpful for managing temperatures and ensuring optimal performance of my system. (I have Arctic 360 AIO, Lian Li PWM Fans + Lian Li UNI Fan P28)
If any of you have come across such programs that are compatible with Ubuntu and provide a solid graphical interface, I'd greatly appreciate your insights.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error using SpeedFan - how can I control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410273/error-using-speedfan-how-can-i-control-fan-speed)