# How to control Cpu/GPu fans in Gigabyte laptops?

Tags: laptop, fancontrol, gigabyte

I tried everything but Im unable to control my fan using ubuntu, In windows there's a built in software that can control my Gpu/Cpu fans so I assume I have pwm sensor but when I tried to use that command I get this message

"/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed"

Model: Gigabyte A5 X1
ryzen 9 5900HX
radeon graphcs / RTX 3070 mobile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error using SpeedFan - how can I control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410273/error-using-speedfan-how-can-i-control-fan-speed)

Comment: When you run `sensors-detect`, it must be able to detect and identify a Super I/O chip in order for pwmconfig to work.  Just because the fans can be controlled does not mean it has PWM support, they can be controlled by voltage as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Coolero

In a terminal you download the appimage with the command:

```
 wget https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/30707566/packages/generic/appimage/latest/Coolero-x86_64.AppImage
```

Once the file is downloaded, you give it the necessary permissions with the command:

```
 chmod +x Coolero-x86_64.AppImage
```

Now you can start the program by double clicking on the file, or by typing in the terminal:

```
 ./Coolero-x86_64.AppImage
```

Comment: After installing that, I only see System overview tab.